# SQLServer Formatear Fecha a YYYYMMDD

Tags: sql-server, sql, date

Favor su ayuda.

Tengo la siguiente tabla `FECHA_REG` SqlServer.

```
ID|FECHA
1 |20180424020549
2 |20180424020500
3 |20180424080010

SELECT TRXSF.iD, TRXSF.FECHA  FROM [ESQUEMA].[dbo].[FECHA_REG ] AS TRXSF;
```

Resultado esperado:

```
ID|FECHA
1 |20180424
2 |20180424
3 |20180424
```

Necesito eliminar la hora, minutos y segundos.

Comment: Conoces la función LEFT()?

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví.

```
SELECT TRXSF.iD, CONVERT(varchar(8),TRXSF.FECHA,112) as FECHA[ESQUEMA].[dbo].[FECHA_REG ] AS TRXSF;
```